# Angular 4.1 + Universal not detecting changes

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, universal

I have upgraded my project (angular2 + universal) to Angular 4.1. I've got my project ready to work but now I have a problem.

Angular is not detecting changes in my model. For example:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title">
      {{title}}
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ftw';
}
```

Variable title never change.

Anyone knows what could be happening?

**EDIT**

An example: https://github.com/Josmorsot/universalng4-error.git

Comment: Any errors? Do you have a minimal working example to reproduce it?

Comment: No, I'm not getting errors. I'm going to create an repo with an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just upload an example https://github.com/Josmorsot/universalng4-error.git

Comment: Your events are running outside angular zone

Comment: Can you explain me this?

Comment: I need to investigate it a bit more. When event is fired outside angular zone it won't trigger change detection cycle http://take.ms/cKmIz

Comment: Shouldn't  be `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` inside `client.ts` instead of `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node`? I compare your demo with https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo

Comment: Yes! I was changing this just now. Your previous response gave me a little clue. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was using 'zone.js/dist/zone-node' instead 'zone.js/dist/zone' at client.ts and client.aot.ts